# Why the asymmetry in LinearLayout.generateDefaultLayoutParams() output?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, layoutparams

According to the docs for the [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) class for the method below:

```
protected LinearLayout.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams ()
```

> Returns a set of layout parameters with a width of MATCH_PARENT and a
>   height of WRAP_CONTENT when the layout's orientation is VERTICAL. When
>   the orientation is  HORIZONTAL, the width is set to WRAP_CONTENT and
>   the height to WRAP_CONTENT.

I first noticed this when looking at the code and thought it might be a mistake
so I looked at the doc for clarification, but found that that doc agreed with the code but with no explanation. Why is it asymmetric like this?

In other words, I'd expect a horizontal layout's default height to be the same as a vertical layout's default width and vice versa.  Why is that not the case?  Without explanation, it seems random and haphazard.